# node.js mongoose TypeError: set is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Pretty new to `Node.js` and `Mongoose`.
Trying to perform a basic `set` action after finding the relevant object, however I get the following error:

> TypeError: {found object}.set is not a function.

The following is the code causing the error:

```
    UserProfile.find({"user": req.params.id}, function (err, userProfile) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("Saving User profile - Error finding user");
    } else { // no error
      if (userProfile) { // if userProfile is found
        console.log("Saving User profile - userProfile found for user: " + userProfile);

        userProfile.set ({
          gender: req.body.gender,
          dob: req.body.dob,
          phone: req.body.phone,
          phone2: req.body.phone2,
          state: req.body.state,
          country: req.body.country
        });
      }
    }
  });
```

The following is the error i receive:

> TypeError: userProfile.set is not a function

If I'm trying to use the "set" function on a new object created based on the same model, it works with no issue

```
var userProfile = new UserProfile ();
userProfile.set ({
  gender: req.body.gender,
  dob: req.body.dob,
  phone: req.body.phone,
  phone2: req.body.phone2,
  state: req.body.state,
  country: req.body.country
});
```

The following is the model:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var UserProfileSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    user: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "User"
    },
    gender: String,
    phone: String,
    phone2: String,
    dob: Date
});


module.exports = mongoose.model ("UserProfile", UserProfileSchema);
```

Comment: Has it occurred to you to log userProfile to console to see what it is?

Answer (score 2):

Use `findOne` not `find`. The former returns an object as the 2nd argument in the callback, the latter returns an array as the 2nd argument in the callback.

Answer (score 1):

`.find` returns an array of documents. try using `.findOne` which returns the first found document